# ASWebAuthenticationSession get Cookies

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, webview, aswebauthenticationsession

im trying to use ASWebAuthenticationSession to authenticate with a private identity provider.

1. Authentication with ASWebAuthenticationSession starts
2. Callback with my custom scheme got called
3. I need all Cookies of this requests to authenticate the User within my WKWebView. The callback only sends me the url of my custom scheme and not the request.

I can't transfer the Cookies within the url of my custom scheme because i reach the maximum length of url.

ASWebAuthenticationSession doesn't use HTTPCookieStorage to store the Cookies while the authentication?!

```
session = ASWebAuthenticationSession(url: urlToCall, callbackURLScheme: scheme)
    { callbackURL, error in
        let cookie = callbackURL?.absoluteString.split(separator: "=")[1]
        print("Session is \(cookie)")
        //How to get Cookies here?
    }
```

Does anyone have solutions?

Comment: Bumping this - there doesn't seem to be documentation about how to set cookies on ASWebAuthenticationSession

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same problem, and unfortunately there is no way to get your cookies using `ASWebAuthenticationSession`

My solution was to use `WKWebView` for authentication rather than `ASWebAuthenticationSession`.

This will give you flexibility to achieve what you need mainly because you'll be able to access cookies from you `WebView`.

The main difference is that you will need to dismiss the WebView manually, and for this I would say we have to options:

1. Once you pass the `origin or callback url` to your auth provider you will receive it in you scene delegate, and from there reach the code where you are presenting your WebView and dismiss it.

```
func scene(
    _ scene: UIScene, 
    openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>
) {
    print("SCENE-DELEGATE : Callback received")
    print(URLContexts)
}
```

2. Implement `WKNavigationDelegate`, and check the redirect URL until it matches the final redirect in your auth process and dismiss the web view from there, this can be done in:

```
func webView(
        _ webView: WKWebView,
        decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction,
        decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void
    ) {
        if navigationAction.request.url?.host == "ssoResult" {
            UIApplication.shared.open(navigationAction.request.url!)
            <dismissYourWebView>
            decisionHandler(.cancel)
            return
        }
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
```

Finally to access the cookies `WKWebView` has it's own cookie storage so you probably don't need to do anything else and should be able to open a new `WKWebView` and this last one should have the cookies already.

Note: To read cookies in your WKWebView you can do do through:

```
WKWebsiteDataStore.default().httpCookieStore.getAllCookies { cookies in
          
      }
```